# How to clear the page while pop in Flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, navigation

I'm setting one Page that shows the Employees List in Card. While pressing on a specific Card, it navigate to another page that shows specific employee details. I added a back button in app bar to pop.
The Problem is when clicked first time, it shows the correct details. But when back button is pressed and another profile is clicked, the screen shows the same previous employee details.
What to know how to clear the Screen while pop in Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

Well with no code or error logs ,its difficult to deduce the source of the error.However you could check into state management of you app, data source (is it fetching the right  data from database, api etc), could you have hard coded the data.

Comment: Solved. The Error is due to my poor program. Anyway thanks!